# Separator in listview is alternatively thick and thin

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem that i have a `listview` for many data items, it shows separator lines very thick and thin alternatively, and when we assign true in "`anydensity`" property in `androidmanifest.xml` this problem was resolved but my images and texts are distorted on multiple resolution, So what is the exact solution for this instead of `anydensity= true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set deviderHeight property for ListView? If yes, is it in density independant pixels?

Comment: yes I have dividerheight property in listview and set as "1dip" but problem remains same.

Comment: As far as I know 1 dip is default value. Try to remove this line from xml (just my suggestion)